# How to resolve object disposed exception ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework and Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to write a controller that receives a request from an AJAX call and performs some calls to the database via the DBContext. However, when I place the command `var user = await GetCurrentUserAsynch();` in front of any calls to the DBContext, as shown below, I get an ObjectDisposedException (Cannot access a disposed object).

It appears to be the UserManager and the DBContext not playing nicely together, however I can't find much information on the matter.

```
[HttpPost]        
public async void EditUserMapItemAjax([FromBody]UserMapItemViewModel userMapItemViewModel)
{            
    var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
    var mapItem = _db.MapItems.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == userMapItemViewModel.MapItemId);   

    ...
}

private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: Which provider are you using? GetUserAsync is just wraps the call around the underlying `IUserStore<T>`

Comment: @Tseng I am new to most of the concepts - .net core, entity, and identity, so I apologize if this doesn't answer your question. In my Startup.ConfigServies I have: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` and `services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();`. Application user extends IdentityUser.

Comment: Identity is backed by a database and the provider connects it. See it as database driver. Which database are you using with Identity? MSSQL? Sqlite? Mysql? Postgresql? In UserManager there is no code which calls dispose, it just delegates it to the provider. The SQLServer provider also has no disposing in it, so I suspect you are using some other provider. Also you don't need to register `services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();` manually, Identity should doing that already, iirc

Comment: @Tseng thanks for the explanation! I'm using MSSQLLocalDB.

Comment: I assume `_db` and `_userManager` are local to your controller.  What is the lifetime of each; i.e. are they both disposed when the controller is disposed, or does one or both outlive the controller (e.g. an injected singleton)?

Comment: @sellotape Yes, everything is local. They are both injected into the constructor of the controller and saved into instance variables. The userManager is set to a Scoped lifetime and I believe the DBContext is Scoped by default.

Comment: Does changing the method declaration to `async Task` instead of `async void` solve it?

Comment: Yes, you should never use async void, because it won't be awaited and exceptions handled with `async void` have different behaviour. Only use them for UI handlers (when making Desktop applications and you write handlers for i.e. button click).

Comment: @sellotape @Tseng I was unaware of the different behavior for `async void`. I switched it to `async Task` and things are working for me now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Declare your controller action as `async Task`, not `async void`.

With the latter, as soon as your method hits the first `await`, it returns control to the caller, and because ASP.NET now has no way to track its progress (as it would have when it returns a `Task` instead), it disposes your controller instance, and (most-likely) along with it any locally-scoped fields.

---

While you're there, as you're in an async method anyway, you should prefer the async version of the EF call; i.e. `await _db.MapItems.SingleOrDefaultAsync()`