# Getting System.ObjectDisposedException when redirecting pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

**Update: The problem was that the OnGet methods was async. Thank you everyone for the help and input!**

In my first page (Home) i'm getting a list of Users:

HomePageModel:

```
public async void OnGetAsync()
    {
            var everything = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
            GetUsers = everything;
    }
```

Then i'm creating a list of the users on the page and a link that redirects to a page that has another list of the users bets:

The HomePage:

```
<ul class="list-group">
@foreach (var user in Model.GetUsers)
{
<li class="list-group-item">
    //Irrelevant stuff
    <a asp-page="./UserBets" asp-route-id="@user.Id">View Bets</a>
</li>
}
</ul>
```

That redirects to UserBets, here's the UserBetsModel:

```
public async void OnGetAsync(string Id)
    {
        if (Id != null)
        {   //Debugging             
            Message += Id;
            using (var db = _context)
            {
                var everything = await _db.Bet.Where(a => a.UserId == Id).Select(s => s.MatchId).SingleAsync();
                GetBets = everything;
            }
        }            
    }
```

When it gets there i'm getting a message that says:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>   Object name: 'AsyncDisposer'.'

I've tried withouth having using scopes, having it on both pagemodels.
The thing is that i don't really understand the problem here, so i'm sorry if i'm not giving you enough context or code but ask if you need more.

What i want to do is print out a list of the users bets.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `async void` is usually best avoided, because there's no way for the calling code to know *when it's finished*. E.g. both of your `OnGetAsync` methods will, at some future point in time, set the `GetBets` or `GetUsers` property. But we've no means of discovering *when* it's been done, so it's likely that more of your code is fragile and subject to data races.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve object disposed exception ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework and Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229637/how-to-resolve-object-disposed-exception-asp-net-core-with-entity-framework-and)

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var db = _context)
{
    var everything = await _context.Bet.Where(a => a.UserId == Id).Select(s => s.MatchId).SingleAsync();
    GetBets = everything;
}
```

Your `using` will dispose of `_context` immediately after the `GetBets = everything;` line. The problem is that `_context` doesn't belong to your method, so any other code that uses `_context` will find it disposed. I imagine you have similar code elsewhere that is disposing of it too, which is probably why the issue is presenting here.

Don't dispose of shared objects until they aren't going to be used anymore (usually when the containing class is destroyed - you should add your own `IDisposable` implementation on the parent class).

Comment: I'm having a using block in another page. But that page doesnt have anything to do with these two, altough it's using the same context. Is that interfering even when the two pages (Home and UserBets) doesnt "talk" to the other page?

Comment: Is `_context` a singleton injected via dependency injection?

Comment: Almost certainly, `_context` doesn't "belong" to you. It's not your job to `Dispose` it, so don't put it in `using` statements.

Comment: In `Startup` i add it in  `ConfigureServices` :  `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); `

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i removed all the using statements but i still get the same message

Comment: @aneko5 - pay attention to my comment in your Q as well. It doesn't look like you're using `async` right so it's possible the real cleanup/dispose is happening whilst some of your code is still running.